# Add custom guid to Marker icon

Tags: ngx-leaflet

Using ngx-leaflet and Angular 7+ TypeScript, how do I go about adding a custom property to store an id/guid for a map icon I placed?

```
var newMarker = marker(
                [markerObj.latitude, markerObj.longitude],
                {

                    icon: icon( {
                        iconSize: [38, 38],
                        iconAnchor: [13, 13],
                        iconUrl: markerObj.iconUrl
                    } ),

                }
            ).on( 'click', () => {
                this.zone.run(() => {
                    this.onMarkerClick( markerObj );
                } );
            } );
```

Comment: You could pass it as a parameter to onMarkerClick, or you could extend the Marker class and add your own extra property.

Comment: I extended the marker class, thanks!